# How to assign Vector3 value to Float64

Tags: ros, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to assign vector3 value to a Float64 variable as my function accepts Float64 arguments. It gives following error

```
no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std_msgs::Float64’ and ‘geometry_msgs::Vector3_<std::allocator<void> >::_z_type {aka double}’)
```

My function is of the following form

```
void calc_cartezian_trajectory(double CT[3][N] , Float64 desX , Float64 desY , Float64 desZ , double initial_pose_end_effector[3])
```

How can I do that ? Is there anyway I can pass vector3 values as vector3.x as parameters to my function ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246542/how-to-assign-vector3-value-to-float64/) by [ZainMehdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28126/zainmehdi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 225 on 2016-10-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZainMehdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28126/zainmehdi/) on 2016-10-26**:
I figured another way out. I passed Vector3 to my function instead of Float64 and it worked. But still a way for type conversion might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I figured another way out. I passed Vector3 to my function instead of Float64 and it worked. But still a way for type conversion might be helpful.

There is no conversion defined for `Vector3` to `Float64` (or really `double`, as the error message tells you). I'm also dubious as to how that would work: C++ type conversions are from one value to another, while `Vector3` packs three values, so a conversion should return another container-like type (a `tuple`, `vector` or something like that) in order to work. That wouldn't really help that much I believe.

> Is there anyway I can pass vector3 values as vector3.x as parameters to my function ?

Well, yes: `geometry_msgs/Vector3` contains `x`, `y` and `z` members, didn't the following work for you?

```
calc_cartezian_trajectory(..., vector3.x, vector3.y, vector3.z, ...)
```

If that is really a problem, you could perhaps create an overloaded version of `calc_cartezian_trajectory(..)` that does take a `geometry_msgs::Vector3` instance, and then calls the one you have now.

PS: slightly off-topic, but `cartezian` -> `cartesian`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZainMehdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28126/zainmehdi/) on 2016-10-27**:
thnx alot for the answer and spelling correction  :p.. cheers !!!